# How to use 也好. Not meaning 'also good'

Tags: word-choice, syntax

My non-Mandarin colleagues have been using

> 英文也好，中文也好

lately and I assumed from their context they meant both languages are equal in whatever comparison they were making.

When I looked it up I found it to mean "might as well, whether...or..."

How can I use 也好？
Is there more (or less) colloquial equivalents?
How is 也罢 different?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Both `A也好, B也好` and `A也罢, B也罢` construction mean "whether A or B". It is usually spoken to show indifference when faced with two options or when the choice really doesn't matter. The explanation from 汉典 says the following:

**A也好, B也好**

> 表示不论这样还是那样都不是条件
>   Example: 插秧也好，收割也好，都不要误了农时。

**A也罢, B也罢**

> 表示不以所列举的情况为条件
>   Example: 运砖也罢，整地也罢，保证超额完成任务。

When used together, people would normally associate 也好 to a *positive* choice or action and 也罢 to a *negative* one. For example:

你去也好，不去也罢，都与我无关。

Note that for this **A也好, B也罢** construction, the sequence is always 也好 first followed by 也罢.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, when using 也好 as "A也好, B也好", it's different than use it alone. I partially confirm the answer provided by Question Overflow, but I don't think there is a different about positive/negative.

If using 也好 alone, like:

> A: 我们去公园吧？(Shall we go to the park?)
>   B: 我们还是去购物吧。(I'd like us to go shopping.)
>   A: 也好。(All right.)

this mean the proposal from another is not same as yours but still acceptable.

Comment: Would this meaning be equivalent to "That's (your proposal) also good/good too" ?

Comment: @tao, You are right but there is a slight different. 也好 is not only meaning that's also good but also to accept the proposal instead. In the example above, the A will go shopping with B after saying 也好.